# how can i get the last value in a line and increment it

Tags: shell

i have a file file.txt
the contents are

element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/RedHat/6/ncurses-devel/5.7-3.20090208.el6.i686/... VERSION_01
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/RedHat/6/ncurses-lib/5.7-3.20090208.el6.i686/... VERSION_02
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/RedHat/6/slang/2.2.1-1.el6.i686/... VERSION_03

is there any way in shell scripting so that i can get the last value in the last line(VERSION_02) and increment it to VERSION_03 and add this line 
element /vob/ccm_tpl/repository/RedHat/6/ncurses-lib/5.7-3.20090208.el6.i686/... VERSION_03
in the same file which i have
please help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The answer to your question is "Yes, there is a way". Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving this question. In particular, it needs to include the code for *your attempt* to solve your problem. We are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could do this .. here's one using a regular expression and perl.

```
perl -i.bak -ple 's/(\d+)\D*$/ sprintf "%02d", $1+1 /e' /path/to/file.txt
```